# Cygwin Path Error: Cannot find module 'C:\cygdrive\c\...'

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, cygwin, npm

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7 and it was working as expected until I updated it a couple of days ago.

Now when I try to run a makefile for my NodeJs app I get the errors about paths. In error stack I see all the paths have double reference to C drive:

```
C:\cygdrive\c\...
```

**Update** : Reproduced in Git bash, Windows command line and Cygwin shells.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I guess you're using MSYS's `git`? [npm/npm#7623](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7623)

Comment: any of these: git, cygwin, cmd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `C:\cygdrive\c` path is a native, Windows-style symbolic link to just `C:\` as that is the expected behavior of that path.

By default, cygwin creates a UNIX-style symbolic link, which won't work well in many cases. So you need to explicitly tell cygwin what to do here.

Here's how, from inside of Cygwin:

```
export CYGWIN="winsymlinks:native"
cd C:/cygdrive && rm -rf c && ln -s -v C:/ c
```

Comment: Exactly, worked for me! Thank you so much for help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for similar question you'll find what you look for.
I think this post answers your question quite well
https://superuser.com/questions/291818/cygwin-cygdrive-paths-and-windows-command-prompt/291820#291820

Comment: Didn't work me for me. I also found [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2465) Gihub link that can be related.