# Not able to launch heroku cli on cygwin

Tags: heroku, cygwin, heroku-cli

As I don't have admin rights on my laptop, so downloaded the zip version of heroku CLI for deploying my app. When I execute the cmd from the bin path of the heroku it's launching and working fine, but when trying to launch from cygwin it's not working. Followed below workaround as I thought path issues, symlinks issues

```
.bash_profile

#Setting the heroku path on the cygwin
    export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/c/Django/heroku/bin/heroku"

    export CYGWIN="winsymlinks:native"
    cd C:/cygdrive && rm -rf c && ln -s -v C:/ c


.bashrc

alias heroku="/cygdrive/c/Django/heroku/bin/heroku"
```

which are suggested in the SO, but not helpful and I'm getting below error when trying to execute $ heroku in cygwin..

```
$ heroku
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\cygdrive\c\Django\heroku\bin\run'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980
:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_ma
in.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Note: I'm able to launch heroku from GIT bash and CMD

Comment: What is the scope of this  `cd C:/cygdrive` ?

Comment: one of the SO answer to the similar problem for module not found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172317/cygwin-path-error-cannot-find-module-c-cygdrive-c)

Comment: you know that `rm -rf c` can destroy your system if something go wrong....

Comment: I thought the command is for changing the symlinks atomically.. correct me if that is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whole time I was adding wrong files to the path and also executing them, Extracted zip folder of heroku contains following files

[image: Extracted zip folder of heroku contains following files]

So, what I did..? copied the full path of bin including heroku.cmd file and pasted in the below file ".bashrc" as alias.

```
.bashrc  

alias heroku="/cygdrive/c/Django/heroku/bin/heroku.cmd"
```

as heroku.cmd file is a script file and it contains set of commands for the heroku.

[image: heroku cli in cygwin]

and I'm able to login to heroku and create app as well.